# What is dummy form that is delaying my computer from shutting down?

Tags: windows-8

I just bought a new computer with windows 8. Often when shutting down the computer I get a message that pops up saying that "dummy form" is delaying windows from shutting down. I have searched for this on the web and found a couple others having the same issue but no answers. It does not take that long for the comp to shutdown but I was wondering what this is.

With this machine being out of the box I am assuming that more have this happening as well and is probably just simply something new about the way windows 8 does apps that I just have yet to udnerstand.

windows 8
Acer Aspire V3-551-8469

If there is anymore information I need to provide, please feel free to ask.

Comment: You're going to have to work with me here, as I am not a Win 8 user. I need you to locate and go to: my computer > find 'uninstall or change a program' > from the list of installed apps that pops up, look for an app named dummy form. If it is not there, I need you to find a search box and type msconfig > startup tab > search for dummy form. Last, if that fails, type 'services.smc' into a search box and select the services icon in the results page. Search listings for dummy form. Note: It's very possible that Win 8 no longer has these areas, if so, let me know and I'll dive deeper into it.

Comment: I did all of that and yet I have yet to find it. Searching for this on the web The others who asked this question said the same thing but so far no answer on anything. I searched all files, services, programs, apps, etc.

Comment: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/protect/forum/protect_other-protect_scanning/prefetch-form-and-dummy-form-are-preventing-my-pc/8ff9b965-4348-42fb-b39a-f8ef730a60c8 Looks like a problem many people have with Windows 8 that hasn't been solved yet...

Comment: Everyone who is having this issue is on the same model computer as you ya?

Comment: @Josh I do not know that information but it seems to be with windows 8 users in general... Including something that says "prefetch form" which I also get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also had this problem on my Acer notebook, after further investigation it seems to happen due to poor programming from a program called Acer Instant Update Service (or something along those lines), which supposedly speeds up the process of obtaining emails but Ive never seen it working so I just deleted the program, by the by it and it solves the problem of the dummy form or its counterpart iuemailoutlookagent hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I got rid of a lot of the acer programs anyway due to it bogging down the computer. I had a feeling it might have something to do with Acer software, but many people that posted their questions did not post what brand of machine they had. I was hoping it was not a Windows 8 issue. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Use MSCONFIG to disable all those dozens of junk processes that load in the "startup" tab, you'll probably also see a handful in the "services" tab.

After you log out then back in again (or reboot) you'll have a whole different experience. I tend to just reinstall my OS from scratch whenever I get a new PC, only takes a few minutes and you don't end up with any remnants of bloatware in the registry or system folders.

To clarify- most are good, often pertaining to Windows processes- but new computers come loaded with extra software which adds numerous entries which are *not* required- and force your lapotop to work a little bit harder (especially at boot time/shutdown).

For most people- the only entries they need under "startup" are their antivirus product. Some other people require Dropbox on boot. But 90% of processes you see in there shouldn't really be in there.

By the way you've cross posted your question on many other websites. When I tried to research "dummy form" all that came up was your exact question, asked all over the internet in the past 2 weeks.

Comment: I saw it here:

http://nerdanswer.com/answer.php?q=51643

But I guess they just link back to this site! My bad :)

Comment: Thanks Dan. I deleted my comment because I saw it did not come across like I wanted. Thank you for taking the time to suggest options for not having to deal with it. Even if I know how to remove it I still like to know what caused it. I took a look at that site you showed and I find that really funny. I didn't realize other sites copied superuser questions. I only ever asked my question on superuser.